# Not displaying a image in mobile but still loading it?

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email

I'm designing a email along with a designer. We want to implement a Gif as a Hero Image in this email. But on Mobile I want to display a different Gif than on Desktop. Since almost all mobile clients support css in the header I inserted the Desktop Image in the Code and then the Mobile Image as a style. This is my code:
CSS:

```
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 470px) {
    span[id=mobile] {
      display:block;
      background-image: url(mobile.gif) !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: center !important;
      width: 320px !important;
      height: 290px !important;
    }
    img[id=desktop] {display: none !important;}
  }
</style>
```

and my HTML:

```
<span id="mobile">
  <img id="desktop" src="desktop.gif" alt="">
</span>
```

Everything works fine, the only issue I have is that each Gif is about 220kb in size. If only one is loaded, I think it's fine for mobile. I think now, allthough I dont display the desktop version, it still loads fully. Is there any workaround so only one loads?

Comment: A 220mb gif is _not_ fine for mobile. An image that big is significantly larger than most apps on my phone, and with my internet speed topping out at 12mbps I can guarantee I would read whatever you have in your email and delete it before your gif was half downloaded.

Comment: I meant 220 kb, sorry!

Comment: Worth noting that selectors (span[id=mobile]) aren't supported in the latest Gmail App - the one that doesn't strip out style entirely. Change it to span#mobile to have whatever you come up with work in Android Gmails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different email clients handle this differently, but have you tried hiding the image in the HTML body and selectively displaying it in media queries? If an image is `display:none;`-ed by default, an email client reading the HTML might not download it right away.

**CSS**

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 470px) {
        img[id=desktop] {
            display: block !important;
        }
    }
</style>

<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 470px) {
        span[id=mobile] {
            display:block;
            background-image: url(mobile.gif) !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-position: center !important;
            width: 320px !important;
            height: 290px !important;
        }
        img[id=desktop] {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="mobile">
    <img id="desktop" src="desktop.gif" alt="" style="display: none;">
</span>
```

Again, not sure if ALL email clients do this.

---

Not sure what clients you focus on, but another option worth testing is `srcset`?

```
<img srcset="small.gif 1x, large.gif 2x" src="small.gif" alt="my gif" border="0">
```

It should cover iOS Mail, though am not sure of coverage beyond that.

Comment: I can verify via litmus, email on acid and live tests that this solution works on the vast majority of email clients.  The only exceptions I have really found have been some Android native clients (less than 1% market) and some versions of Android Gmail app - that have not yet received the stylesheet update (very tiny margin).  I would also add the !mso conditional around the mobile image version as well, to make sure both don't show up in replies and forwards on Outlook.  srcset is not widely accepted though.

Comment: @Gortonington brilliant idea regarding the `<!--[if !mso]>`, I've updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the testing by Gortonington! I'll implement this and test it aswell. Do you know if there is a tool that measures email file size on different clients?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the too large image file (220MB? - uh uh...) you should do it the other way round, like first define the background image for mobile and then *in a media query*  like `min-device-width: 471px` the one for desktop. That way the desktop image won't be loaded on mobile devices.

Comment: I did it this way around because for example Outlook won't use the styles in the head. And most Mobile clients do. Also I meant 220kb, sorry for the mistake.